# Java char array equality not functioning

Tags: java, arrays, char, equals

I have an assignment that requires use of a socket. On the client and server side I have 
char[] value= "END STREAM".toCharArray(), which signals the stream to shutdown.

Since I have both these arrays in the 2 different files, my intention is that the client sends the message value > the server. Then the server does the function

```
while(!Arrays.equals(clientSentence, value))
{
...
inFromClient.read(clientSentence, 0, length);  //to read in from client side
.....
}
```

In essence, while it does not send the END STREAM message, keep reading. My issue is that the array equality does not work as intended. I even test this by doing

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(value, clientSentence));
System.out.println(new String(value));
System.out.println(new String(clientSentence));
```

and it prints

```
false
END STREAM
END STREAM
```

How can it be false when it is printing the same values. I have made sure that both arrays initialize to the same length so where is it going wrong? I have been stuck on this for hours and searched for answers but cannot find a solution. Thanks

EDIT: added my read function. I use a BufferedReader

Comment: Printed strings are often deceptive. I think you should print `clientSentence` character by character (ASCII code by ASCII code) and make sure that `clientSequence.length == 9` (maybe there's some unprintable characters in there or a zero byte)

Comment: Could you please show the specific functions that sends and receives these messages and the declarations of these arrays in both server and client.

Comment: Remarkably, Java isn't broken. It means the two arrays you're comparing aren't equal. Using the debugger would quickly show you why.

Comment: Brian has a good point, check this puppy out in the debugger and watch for whitespace characters in either of the arrays, casing in some of the chars...something that makes them different.

Comment: Also you said you added a read function that uses a BufferedReader but I don't see it.

Comment: Print the byte arrays themselves, with Arrays.toString. See if they both have the same bytes. You haven't shown that value and clientSentence are the same.

Comment: In my send function, on the client side I have
   outToServer.write(value);
   outToServer.flush();

then it reads in as 
inFromClient.read(clientSentence, 0, length);

So maybe my issue is that the extra characters(of size length) which make the array unequal, but when i do println both the arrays, it prints the same output so I'm not so sure

Is it maybe that the server side array clientSentence is longer length than the sent array?

Answer (score 1):

On my box:

```
char[] x = "END STREAM".toCharArray();
char[] y = "END STREAM".toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(x, y));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
```

works which makes me think a few things:

1. The arrays, as declared in your code, are not equal.
2. There is a character set incompatibility, you said you were using a BufferedReader and, if you're using the Files.newBufferedReader() functionality of Java 1.7, you need specify a charset when using it which may be causing a problem.
3. End of line issues either from cross platform systems or something else e.g. \r vs \n

Thinking a little more about it...it's probably #2, check this out for further information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html